# jquery equivalent of form.field_name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

with native form DOM element I can access its field using the input name:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="input-name" />
</form>

var form = document.getElementById("form");
form["input-name"] // or form.input_name if it wasn't an hyphen.
```

What will be the same with jquery? by same I mean same lookup.
using `form.find("[name='input-name']")` is not the same in terms of performance, the form native method is simply an object lookup, jquery will use querySelectorAll.

Comment: `$('#FORM_ID [name="FIELD_NAME"]')` __OR__ `$('#FORM_ID').find('[name="FIELD_NAME"]')`

Answer (score 0):

`$('#form [name="input-name"]')`

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this using [`Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):-

```
$('#form [name="input-name"]')
// Find the elements with name attribute selector within a form with id `form`
```

Or using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) like

```
$('#form').find('[name="input-name"]')
// Search through the descendants of `#form` in the DOM tree
```

Or if you can put some id to the input text, you can just do

```
$('#inputID')
// As id are supposed to be unique in DOM no need to Search through 
// the descendants of `#form`, just call the element by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object by using the following selector:

> $("input[type='text'][name='input-name']");

Comment: but that is worse in terms of performance, with native DOM form element it is simply an object indexing. Can't I access to the form object elements as if it was a native DOM element ?